# class path resource [app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: maven, configuration, project, application.properties

I'm trying to do configuration in maven project. I have created app.properties file but when I'm trying to run code, it is showing "class path resource [app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist".
Could anybody help me out please

I tried to run but not getting desired output, getting error like "class path resource [app.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist"

Comment: First you should add more detailed information what kind of app your are trying (spring boot??) etc. how the setup looks etc. which JDK, Maven version etc. log output is helpful... otherwise it's hard to even guess..

Comment: Knowing where you did place the app.properties file would also help